# Angular App in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, iframe

I wrote angular application (web chat) and it works perfectly. Need to integrate it with main website appeared and i decided to integrate it using iframe. For this purposes i wrote small JS file for main website, which create iframe inserts in necessary place. The problem is when I want to load angular app to iframe asynchronously vi AJAX it loads content, but app not initialized. When I just specify src attribute for iframe it loads app normally. Have you ever faced this problem with iframes ? What am i doing wrong ?

```
//Specify URL for iframe - works
(function(url, lang) {

    function init() {
        var footer = document.getElementsByClassName('footer');
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        iframe.src = url + "#/auth/" + lang + "";
        footer[0].parentNode.insertBefore(iframe, footer[0]);
    }

    function fetchChat(response) {
        var o = new XMLHttpRequest;
        o.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (4 == o.readyState && 200 == o.status) {
                applyChatToIframe(o.response);
            }
        }, o.open("GET", url, !0), o.send(null) 
    }

    function applyChatToIframe(response) {
        document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0].contentDocument.write(response);
    }

    init();

})(SOME_URL, conf.lang || "az");




//Trying to load angular app via AJAX to iframe - doesnt work
(function(url, lang) {

    function init() {
        var footer = document.getElementsByClassName('footer');
        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        footer[0].parentNode.insertBefore(iframe, footer[0]);
        fetchChat(url + "#/auth/" + lang + "");
    }

    function fetchChat(response) {
        var o = new XMLHttpRequest;
        o.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (4 == o.readyState && 200 == o.status) {
                applyChatToIframe(o.response);
            }
        }, o.open("GET", url, !0), o.send(null) 
    }

    function applyChatToIframe(response) {
        document.querySelectorAll('iframe')[0].contentDocument.write(response);
    }

    init();

})(SOME_URL, conf.lang || "az");
```

Comment: Where is the Angular library loaded?  Main frame or in the iframe?  The iframe needs it's own instance of the library unless you are going to do a lot of interframe communication.

Comment: @zero298 everything related angular app is loaded inside iframe. That's why the first example works, but second not.

Comment: @bigweb Did you find a solution? I am trying to host two angular apps in inframe